# MySQL: alter the columns of my PRIMARY KEY

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table with the following primary key:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`Id`,`InputOutputConfigurationServerAccountId`,`Identifier`)
```

I want to modify this so that the PK is only the `Id` column. How do I do this?

Comment: `DROP PRIMARY KEY`, `ADD PRIMARY KEY ...`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you have `Id` defined as `auto_increment`.  You need to first change it to just plain int, them make the changes, then turn it back to auto_increment.
Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE SO1 MODIFY COLUMN ID INT;
ALTER TABLE SO1 DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE SO1 ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE SO1 MODIFY COLUMN ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Here's a test of the above (btw, I got the error you mentioned in your comment on other answer if I didn't first modify the column):

```
drop table if exists SO1;
create table SO1 (
  id int auto_increment,
  InputOutputConfigurationServerAccountId int,
  Identifier int,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`,`InputOutputConfigurationServerAccountId`,`Identifier`)
);
ALTER TABLE SO1 MODIFY COLUMN ID INT;
ALTER TABLE SO1 DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE SO1 ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE SO1 MODIFY COLUMN ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT;
show create table SO1;
```

All executed OK. Final Output:

```
CREATE TABLE `SO1` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `InputOutputConfigurationServerAccountId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Identifier` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
)
```

Answer (score 6):

1. Remove the old PK
   `ALTER TABLE table_name DROP PRIMARY KEY`
2. Add the new PK
   `ALTER TABLE table_name ADD PRIMARY KEY (Id)`

Comment: Mike, when I try to drop the primary key, I get the following error: `#1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key`

Comment: Remove the auto_increment before.